# Trying to find the win/loss probability based on the previous result

Tags: r, probability

I am new to data science and I came across this exercise that I can't figure out.

I have a data set containing binary data, which represents win and loss for the team. I wanna find out the probability for the win and loss depending on the result of the previous game.

Something like this.

```
                      win     loss

     prev win          ?        ?

     prev loss         ?        ?
```

I am not asking for the code here. Though it would be helpful if you do. I just want to understand how to go about doing it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Generally, it's best to show what you've already tried. In the future, give it your best shot and if you get stumped, post a new question! Ideally, a good question is one that uses code we can use on our own machines (reproducible example). Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can generate that `prop.table` by comparing the result to the lagged (previous) result:

```
library(dplyr)
results <- data.frame(results = rbinom(100,1, 0.5)) %>% 
  mutate(prev_result = lag(results))

prop.table(table(results$prev_result, results$results))
```